# How to maintain a viewable and editable version of the same HTML form

Tags: php, html

What are some best practices for maintaining a viewable and editable version of the same HTML form?

I have an application that has a lot of custom data-entry screens (with many dozens, sometimes hundreds of fields), and I hate to have to maintain viewable and editable versions of each form layout...

I’m currently refactoring to have two PHP classes one for:

```
class ViewableFormTemplate {
    public static function dsp_textbox($field_name, $row) {
        echo $row[$field_name];
    }
}
```

… and another like:

```
class EditableFormTemplate {
    public static function dsp_textbox($field_name, $row) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="$field_name" value="'. $row[$field_name] .'>';
    }
}
```

And then I’ll call the dsp_textbox() method from the appropriate class depending on which “mode” (viewable or editable) I’m using.

… this all seems a little silly though… is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the distinction in the first place?
Anyway, how about you just put it all in one function in one class, and determine the kind of output based on a boolean flag you (optionally) pass along?

```
class FormTemplate {
    public static function dsp_textbox($field_name, $row, $editable = false) {
        if ($editable)
            echo sprintf('<input type="text" name="%s" value="%s">',
                         $field_name,
                         $row[$field_name]
            );
        
        else
            echo $row[$field_name];
    }
}
```

I'm sure you get the notion. Be aware though, that if the value contains a double quote or a set of < angle brackets > just to name a few, that your html will break. You'll have to [urlencode](https://www.php.net/urlencode) the value before you echo it.

Comment: This is essentially the same approach as the OP... just a little different syntax. Isn't there some better way to approach this issue?